# How to reshape/rearrange this list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

**Problem:**

How can I reshape/convert the following list of numpy arrays to the desired output? I would like to understand exactly how/why it works, so a step-by-step guide would much be appreciated, because I will have to work a lot with mixed numpy.array / list cases.

**Minimal Example**

```
import numpy as np

# create some dummy data
points1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[101, 102, 103]])
points2 = np.array([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8],[104, 105, 106, 107, 108]])
points3 = np.array([[9, 10, 11, 12],[109, 110, 111, 112]])

# gather data / this kind of list is what I will have to work with
points = [points1, points2, points3]

# what it looks like now
print(points)

# do some fance reshape/rearrange stuff
# new_points = ???

# desired output:
# new_points[0] = [1, 101]
# new_points[1] = [2, 102]
# new_points[2] = [3, 103]
# ...
# new_points[11] = [12, 112]
```

I only have access to *points* (not *points1* etc.) and it will be a list of numpy arrays, that are all shaped (2, n).
Are there any short, fancy indexing operations or would I have to go with a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that they are a list of numpy arrays, that are all shaped `(2, n)`, we can simply use one of the stacking functions.

So, with `points = [points1, points2, points3]`, we would have few options to solve it.

```
np.hstack(points).T
np.concatenate(points,axis=1).T
np.column_stack(points).T
```

Or as [`@Mad Physicist suggested`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817537/how-to-reshape-rearrange-this-list-of-numpy-arrays/47817624#comment82597650_47817624) with `np.c_` -

```
np.c_[tuple(points)].T
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not have diret access to "points1 .. 3", I onlye have the list "points". I have edited the opening post to clarify this.

Comment: @OlbertDämmerer. Just replace `[points1, points2, points3]` with `points` for the last two options, or do `np.c_[*points].T` for the first one

Comment: @MadPhysicist is a clairvoyant. He answered your question, before you edited it.

Comment: @Piinthesky. Divakar usually has similar solutions to mine, but thinks much faster, so I find it easier to just make snide comments on his answers most of the time :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I could not get that `np.c_` to work for given `points`. Are you sure it works?

Comment: @Divakar. It does not. Let me fiddle with it for a second. It *should* work.

Comment: @Divakar. The correct syntax is `np.c_[tuple(points)].T`. That was a foolish mistake on my part.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Think you should add that as a new post. Seems shortest :)

Comment: I feel bad doing that. You wrote the solution, I just recast it to use `points` instead of `poins1, points2, ...`

Comment: `concatenate` is the basic operation.  `hstack` is a wrapper, and `c_` is a more complex wrapper.  `c_` requires the tuple because it uses the `[]` indexing notation.

Answer (score 0):

check this simple solution :

```
new_points = np.concatenate([points1.T, points2.T, points3.T])
```

But if you don’t have access to point1, point2 , .. you can recast it as suggested in comments like this:

```
new_points = np.concatenate([x.T for x in points])
```

Comment: OP just mentioned that you don't have direct access to the individual sub-arrays.

Comment: Your solution would work for OP if you recast it as `np.concatenate([x.T for x in points])`, which is what I commented for Divakar's answer a while back.